# База данных для семантического анализа?

Tags: база-данных

Добрый день , у меня в университете задача сделать приложение для Семантического анализа текста и в нем обязательно должна быть База Данных . Помогите мне определить что вообще должно быть в этой базе ! Если есть я б посмотрел пример.